# Reading from cv2.VideoCapture fails on macOS 11.3.1

Tags: python, macos, camera, opencv

I'm trying to read frames from the webcam on a Macbook Pro with OpenCV.

Opening a `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` turns the camera indicator green (and all other indexes are out of range), and `.isOpened()` returns `True`.  However, using `.read()` on the videocapture object returns `(False, Null)`.

I've tried both the `pip` and `brew` versions of OpenCV, and I've tried using both Terminal.app and Kitty, yet the same issue occurs (both have camera perms in System Preferences).

Not really sure what's going on here.  Delaying doesn't help either.

Example:

```py
>>> import cv2
>>> vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
>>> vc.isOpened()
True
>>> vc.read()
(False, None)
```

Comment: not sure if this is cv2 issue or webcam, did you tried with a video file if it captures the frame? something like this `vc = cv2.VideoCapture("somevideofile.mov")`

Comment: @simpleApp Works fine when capturing from a video file.

Comment: so you would need to focus on the webcam, check if there is some security that is disabling the feed.

Comment: @simpleApp oh apparently my camera is broken, oops :b

Comment: oh sorry about that, at least cv2 is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I didn't realize that the camera was not working at all.

The solution ended up being to reset the SMC.